# How to select the directories such that TeX Live is installed in my home?

Tags: texlive, linux

I would like to install TeX Live in my home folder, so that I do not have to reinstall it each time I change from one Linux distribution to another.

When installing TeX Live through the `install-tl` script the following is shown:

```
 <D> directories:
   TEXDIR (the main TeX directory):
     !! default location: /usr/local/texlive/2015
     !! is not writable or not allowed, please select a different one!
   TEXMFLOCAL (directory for site-wide local files):
     /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local
   TEXMFSYSVAR (directory for variable and automatically generated data):
     /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-var
   TEXMFSYSCONFIG (directory for local config):
     /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-config
   TEXMFVAR (personal directory for variable and automatically generated data):
     ~/.texlive2015/texmf-var
   TEXMFCONFIG (personal directory for local config):
     ~/.texlive2015/texmf-config
   TEXMFHOME (directory for user-specific files):
     ~/texmf
```

How do I modify these directories such that I have a "robust" TeX Live installation?

Comment: Change all `/usr/local/texlive` to `~/hometexlive`; your `PATH` variable should then contain `~/hometexlive/2015/bin/<arch>`; of course you should make `~/hometexlive` in advance. Choose the name you like.

Answer (score 5):

### Answer 1: using installer options

When you run `./install-tl`, you will get some options denoted by `<...>`.
When you hit <kbd>D</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> you can change the TeX home directory from `/usr/local/texlive/2018` to `/home/your_user/texlive/2018`.
The other paths should automatically change as well.

Don't forget to update your path after installation! You can do this for example by putting `export PATH="/home/user_name/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH"` in `~/.profile`. Then you have to logout and login, you can test the installation with `latex small2e`.

See https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html for the more installation documentation.

### Answer 2: using environment variables

From [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29784261/4126843): you can set the environment variables below *before* installing texlive, so execute

```
export TEXLIVE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/your_user/texlive
export TEXLIVE_INSTALL_TEXDIR=/home/your_user/texlive/2018
```

and then run `./install-tl` like normal.

Don't forget to update your path after installation! You can do this for example by putting `export PATH="/home/user_name/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH"` in `~/.profile`. Then you have to logout and login, you can test the installation with `latex small2e`.

See https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html for the more installation documentation.

### Answer 3: using texlive.profile

You can also use a `texlive.profile` (this also gives you more control about options), either by copying an example or selecting 'save installation profile to `texlive.profile`' when installing, and then change all `/usr/local/` paths to `/home/your_user`. Then you can install with `./install-tl --profile=texlive.profile`.

An example `texlive.profile` is

```
# texlive.profile written on Tue Jan 15 17:15:41 2019 UTC
# It will NOT be updated and reflects only the
# installation profile at installation time.
selected_scheme scheme-basic
TEXDIR /home/user_name/texlive/2018
TEXMFCONFIG ~/.texlive2018/texmf-config
TEXMFHOME ~/texmf
TEXMFLOCAL /home/user_name/texlive/texmf-local
TEXMFSYSCONFIG /home/user_name/texlive/2018/texmf-config
TEXMFSYSVAR /home/user_name/texlive/2018/texmf-var
TEXMFVAR ~/.texlive2018/texmf-var
binary_x86_64-linux 1
instopt_adjustpath 0
instopt_adjustrepo 1
instopt_letter 0
instopt_portable 0
instopt_write18_restricted 1
tlpdbopt_autobackup 1
tlpdbopt_backupdir tlpkg/backups
tlpdbopt_create_formats 1
tlpdbopt_desktop_integration 1
tlpdbopt_file_assocs 1
tlpdbopt_generate_updmap 0
tlpdbopt_install_docfiles 0
tlpdbopt_install_srcfiles 0
tlpdbopt_post_code 1
tlpdbopt_sys_bin /usr/local/bin
tlpdbopt_sys_info /usr/local/share/info
tlpdbopt_sys_man /usr/local/share/man
tlpdbopt_w32_multi_user 1
```

Answer 2 was tested on Arch Linux 4.20.1 with TeX Live 2018, answer 1 was tested on Fedora.